# Render Order of Transparent Mesh on Unity3D UI canvas

Tags: unity3d-2dtools, unity3d-gui, unity-game-engine

I have a procedural mesh of a 2D circle attached to a ScreenSpace-Camera UI canvas and I want to render some UI text on top of it. However the UI text is always rendered below the circle despite me sorting their z-order. If I change to material to some opaque material, everything works fine. So how do I handle the transparent render order for mesh objects that are treated as a UI element

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the UI Canvas 'Order in Layer' = 1

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice I think you should have one camera only for UI rendering and another for the scene.